# What events are fired when jquery assigns to innerHtml

Tags: jquery

I have the following code which loads some html (which includes anchors) into a div when I click on a link in navMenu.  When I step through it, the `<p>'s` are hidden, but they are not hidden when the page finally appears.  After page is displayed, contentClickFunction hides/shows `<p>'s` as expected.

I believe I need something like 'ready' but for assigning to innerHtml.  Is there an event I can listen for so my call to hide is not overridden?

I know I can achieve my goal by adding css setting `#content li>p { display:none; }` but I want to understand what is going on.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#content").on("click", "li>a", contentClickFunction);
    $("#navMenu a").click(function(event){
        var href = $(this).attr("href");
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get( href , function(data){
            $("#content").html(data);
        });
        $("#content li > p").hide();
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM `ready` fires only once.

You can use [mutation events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents) (`DOMNodeInserted`), but they are deprecated.

You can also create a custom event:

```
function handler(){
    // Do stuff
}

$('#content').on('insert', handler);

$.get( href , function(data){
    $("#content").html(data).trigger('insert');
});
```

The last option seems to be the best for you.

Comment: Thanks.  This works although it still seems that there should be a built in event which indicates that the document has been laid out.  Perhaps this is what DOMContentLoaded will be in HTML5?

Comment: @LenB. I'm afraid there isn't a built-in and good event for DOM changes. `DOMContentLoaded` is like the `ready` event of jQuery. (Actually, jQuery is using it...)